# using and securing Sharding data

Tags: azure-sql-database, sharding, access-control, azure-elastic-sharding

According to the description from Azure [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/what-is-database-sharding/), you use Sharding when you want to split large databases into smaller components.

We want to use Sharding data, not because we have large amount of data, but because we have almost same schema from different organizations.

I need some advice and opinions about having multi-tenancy architecture and sharding databases for organization-related data. Is Sharding a suitable solution? How should you secure data that the users from organizations should have access to their own organization data only.

Comment: May be you can ref these documents: [sharding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-scale-introduction#sharding) and [Multi-tenant and single-tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-scale-introduction#multi-tenant-and-single-tenant). For your situation "have almost same data from different organizations.", I'm afraid it may not suit you.

Comment: Thanks Leon Yue, I have uppdated my question. We have same data schema but different data.